# Contribution form with both Stripe and Paypal

Tags: civicontribute

I have a contribution form that allowed payment by both paypal and stripe. It used to work. Now when a donor checks paypal, nothing happens. The java script reports it is trying to access stripe.com.
Any suggestions.

I am using:
CiviCRM 5.4.1.
PayPal_Standard is shown in Settings | Payment Processor
Stripe is also shown in Settings | Payment Processor
latest stripe extension is used
There is nothing in Settings | Payment Method that indicates PayPal
just checks and credit cards

Unfortunately, I don't know when it stopped working.
But I think I tested it after updating to the latest Stripe extension.

Has anybody else reported this problem?

Comment: We can help you better with more information.  Could you please edit your question to indicate a) which version of the Stripe extension you're using; b) whether you're using PayPal Standard, Pro, or Express; c) your version of CiviCRM; d) the last version of CiviCRM that it used to work with, assuming that this happened as a result of an upgrade.